# Why Vercel serverless endpoint console does not show console.log lines?

Tags: typescript, next.js, serverless, vercel

I have lines like

```
console.log('product', product)
```

in serverless inapoint i.e. `/api/hello` but Vercel does not show those comments, why?

Anyway, what is wrong here, why `u` or `product` is not found?

```js
what is wrong here, why it is not found?

const u = await collection.findOne({ _id: ObjectId(userId) })
console.log('u', u)
const product = u?.products?.[productId]
console.log('product', product)
```